# the effect of Moving average parameter and autoregressive parameter on MA(1)and AR(1) demand process, respectively

Tags: time-series, arima, interpretation, intuition

A time series  follows an MA(1),

$$ d(t) =c+e(t)−\theta \cdot e(t−1) $$

or AR(1),

$$ d(t)=c+e(t)+\phi \cdot d(t-1)$$

What is the the effect of moving average parameter,$\theta$, and autoregressive parameter, $\phi$, on demand process? How can we explain that intuitively? What are the properties of the process and how they will change when we move parameters from -1 toward +1?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No it's not, just I want to understand